# checking an access file via java and mailing for a specific row

Tags: java, ms-access, scheduling, jet, jackcess

I need to write a program that checks a access .mdb file and when a specific row is added (say the "name" field column of the newly added a row that contains a specific string, it should send an email to a specific address.

For this I am planning to use "[Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/)" library for reading the mdb file and  "Apache's commons-email library" for SMTP mailing. However I am not sure which library of Java can be used to execute this "row check" every X time.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to run your application periodically or do you want to check the file periodically from within your running application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy for the program to run continuously, I'd use Quartz (http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). Otherwise a cronjob...

Answer (score 1):

[Jcrontab](http://jcrontab.sourceforge.net/) might work for you, as you can keep it all in your java application.  (This would assume your app is always running, and you want it to periodically check the file while doing other things too.  Like in a webapp.)

> Jcrontab is a scheduler written in
>   Java. The project objective is to
>   provide a fully functional schedules
>   for Java projects.